# Migrate 25 stored procedures on the source database from SQL server to Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration

Migrate 25 stored procedures on the source database from SQL server to Oracle database,  Is it possible any script will do this or Manual work is required

Comment: Totally no details about the procedures, so I'll say manual work.

Answer (score 1):

Manual work is certainly required. The databases don't support the same procedural languages so you're going to have to rewrite them.

SQL Servers [Transact-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) is a different language than Oracle's [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL)